# Javascript regex - get string between two matches, multiple times

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove all style rules like this `<style>blablabla</style>` including `<style>` tag.
I'm using the following script to accomplish this

```
  var text = '<   style  type= "text/css"  > hello1  <  /  sTyle  > 
               some text
              <   style  type= "text/css"  > hello2  <  /  sTyle  >';

  var regX = /< *style .*>([\s\S]*?)< *\/ *style *>/ig;
  text.replace(regX, "");
```

but it removes the whole text including "some text" between two style definitions. I want to keep "some text" in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
< *style .*>
```

The `.*` matches everything.

Change your regex to

```
/< *style .*?>([\s\S]*?)< *\/ *style *>/ig
```

or

```
/< *style [^>]*>([\s\S]*?)< *\/ *style *>/ig
```

---

Note, however that currently your regex misses cases, for example

```
<style></style>
```

You may consider using an actual HTML parser.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to avoid this `.*` greedy fellow in a RegEx. Try something like:

`text.replace(/< *style[\w"= \/]*>[\w ]*<[ \/]*style *>/ig, '')`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/7KSU4/3/)